# Best practice for raise error in Oracle with complex error state data

Tags: oracle, error-handling

`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` in Oracle is a command which send error signal.

> RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(< Error_code >, < Error_message > [, True | False]);

By this way I notify details of error in a string data type which occurs in DB side, But it is not enough! I need to get some other data about current state of the error and value of some of logical local variable in my procedure, data from some tables, ... , In client side (`.Net` application)

A simple and quick answer is using serialization methods such as producing `JSON` and pass it through `ErrorMessage` parameter. is it good way? or are you have any better solutions?

Comment: Is this information the caller needs to be able to understand - so (as a crude option) could parse out of error string? Or do you just need to include data in the error string in a human-readable form?

Comment: I need them, furthermore they affect to performance of the caller app.

Comment: Consider creating special package for error handling. You may define your own `pk_errors.raise_app_error()` and pass to it any data you wish.